# PHP curl get request slow speed

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework, drupal

I use **curl** in custom **Zend Framework** library to make a **GET** request to a **Drupal** website. On the **Drupal** end I use rest export pages that receive get request and return some data.

This is my **curl** request structure in the **ZF2**

```
$this->chanel = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->chanel, CURLOPT_URL, "SOME URL LINK");
curl_setopt($this->chanel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($this->chanel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($this->chanel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');
$result=curl_exec ($this->chanel);
curl_close ($this->chanel);
```

Both **Drupal** and **Zend Framework** websites are located on my **localhost**.

The execution time normally takes around **15 seconds**. This is too long.

I tried the same link with a **Restlet Client (Chrome Extension)** and it takes around **1 second** or less to execute and retrieve the data.

Do you have any suggestions why it is so slow and how I can improve the speed?

Comment: Run [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) after curl_exec, it could help.

Comment: It shows **200**

Comment: It returns more than that without option, read the doc.

Comment: It is too long t o post it here. The important thing is that the total_time is 18.047. The same as the starttransfer_time.

Comment: can you show drupal side code ? are you using services module ?

Comment: @Fky, It is a standart Rest Export view.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting some loggers in your code, put time stamps in various code blocks and inside functions, check if curl is taking time or something else? Put timestamps and loggers after each line to debug the performance issue.

Also try using it from command line as follows:

```
curl --get "URL HERE"
```

And check if its fast or not, if its fast, the code you assume to be slow, try executing the direct command from your code.

Comment: I already did that. It is the curl_exec that that takes long time. On the command line everything works fast.

Comment: try executing the command line then from code using exec() function

Comment: Same, unfortuantely

Comment: That is kinda weird, if exec() function is taking time, then there is nothing really we can do. You will have to find a solution yourself.

Comment: You said you tried it using curl from the command line. Was that from the server that your Zend Framework application is running from? Since you are connecting to localhost, does it make a difference if you use 127.0.0.1 instead? Adding the output of `curl -v yoururl` to your question might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `ip address` instead of `hostname`.
If your Drupal in same machine with your ZF2 app, you can use `127.0.0.1`.
I think that can be caused by DNS look up.

Comment: It is not, both websites are located on the same server and the as I wrote above dns lookup doesn't take any time